# react-create-app - get error about browserslist error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just used `npx create-react-app project-name` and when I'm starting my project I'm getting this error:

> /src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
>   BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query android all. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made a typo in the query.

```
Npm -v : 6.9.0
Node -v : v10.16.0
Windows 10 Pro
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem will be solved after install browserslist

```
npm i browserslist@4.6.3
```

Comment: Nothing has changed, another solution helped: In package.json add "resolutions": { "browserslist": "4.6.2", "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30000974" }

Comment: package.json "resolutions" works for yarn only. npm doesn't support this. there's a package which adds this functionality https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions#readme. But it has it's issues as well, check Issues.

Answer (score 5):

It is a new bug in BrowserList.

Below the workaround given on the GitHub issue is to change the browserslist entry in package.json to

```
"browserslist": []
```

This will build and run the project.

Comment: it works for me, but I think it's better solution to update browserslist@4.6.3 because it's a bug of browserslist package and they release some dirty fix.